# HTTP PUT method on NodeMCU/ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, http

I've been trying to send a put request from my esp8266 for a while not but I can't figure out why it doesn't work and there are barely any posts about put requests online 
I keep getting errors around `int httpCode = http.sendRequest("PUT", String(data));`

Error log: https://gist.github.com/dkbay/ab3fedf5e89d841d25b24fb829df74ef

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define LED_BUILTIN 2

const char* ssid     = "Some SSDI";
const char* password = "Some wifi password";     

int wifiStatus;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);\
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  delay(200);



  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Your are connecting to;");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

}   

void loop() {
  wifiStatus = WiFi.status();

  if(wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED){

    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin("http://google.com/");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String data = "{\"on\":false}";
    int httpCode = http.sendRequest("PUT", String(data));
    String payload = http.getString();

    Serial.println(httpCode);
    Serial.println(payload);

    http.end();
     Serial.println("");
     Serial.println("Your ESP is connected!");
     Serial.println("Your IP address is: ");
     Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected");
  }
  delay(1000); // check for connection every once a second

}
```

Comment: what should it do and what does it? Shouldn't 'false' in json be in ""?

Comment: @Juraj It wasn't in quotes when I made it in node... It should send a "PUT" request to my hue lights to update them but instead it htrows this error https://gist.github.com/dkbay/ab3fedf5e89d841d25b24fb829df74ef

Comment: it doesn't compile, 
not "doesn't work". use  `sendRequest("PUT", data.c_str());`

Answer (score 1):

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://google.com?on=false");
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
int httpCode = http.sendRequest("PUT", "");
String payload = http.getString();
```

try with this code, if server .php,
get data by $_REQUEST